# Why Page Control dot change from One Page to next page

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimage, uipagecontrol

I am working on an ipad application in which we are showing the lots of images on scrollview and and i have added the page controll on bottom, when we are scrolling the image from one page to next page it scroll fine and smoothly but i don't  know why the page controll dot takes time to changing from one dot to other dot i.e when i scroll from one page to next page page reaches to next page immediately but page control dot takes some time any one please tell me why this is happening, any help is highly appreciated. My Code On ScrollViewDidScroll is-

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {

    Paddle8Singleton *paddle8Singleton = [Paddle8Singleton sharedMaster];       
    CGFloat pageWidth = sender.frame.size.width;
    DebugLog(@"current offsetX %f and cus offset %f",sender.contentOffset.x,sender.frame.size.width*currIndex);
    int page;
    if ([paddle8Singleton.selectedFilteredArtistDetailsDict count]>2) {

        page = floor((sender.frame.size.width*currIndex - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    }
    else{
        page = floor((sender.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;                
    }

    if([self ShowAlternateImageButtonForCurrentArtwork:page]&& barsHidden)
    {
        secondaryImageButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        secondaryImageButton.hidden = NO;
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:secondaryImageButton];
    }
    else
    {
        secondaryImageButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        secondaryImageButton.hidden = YES;
    }

    pageControll.currentPage = page;
    self.selectedImageIndex = page;
    [self updateInfoView:page];
}
```

Thanks:

Answer (score 1):

You should not do with the sender.

```
CGFloat pageWidth = self.yourview.frame.size.width;
int page = floor((self.yourview.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
```